# Define an array/vector property type in Add Property Wizard of VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

In my visual Studio solution, in my '.odl file', I would like to have a vector/array property type, "sample", and this array/vector of sample would hold a list for it be accessed across platforms. To do this, I had to click on the right file to add a property within the class view.

I am trying to add an array/vector property type in the Add Property Wizard of VS2010, but there seems to be no such array/vector related property type. I also tried setting my own property type, vector, this gives me an error, "Property type must be a variant-compatible type from the list."

But, I dont see any array/vector supported property type in the list.  Is there a way this could be done?

Comment: Is there any way this could be done?

Comment: this link here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dffbw6e.aspx just enables accessing of one element, how do I get the entire list?